# List Of Common English Syntax Ambiguities?

Tags: syntax, ambiguity

For an example of ambiguous syntax:

```
John likes Adam more than Eve.
```

Such a construction could mean that:

```
Comparing Adam and Eve, John likes Adam more.

Compared to Eve's liking of Adam, John likes Adam more.
```

Is there a list anywhere of common distinct ambiguous English syntax?

EDIT:

I've edited this to note that I'm just looking for a list of common syntax ambiguities. I'm not expecting a complete list, for I know that there's not a finite quantity of syntax ambiguities.

Comment: No, there are infinitely many such ambiguities.

Comment: So are you looking for a corpus-based statistical analysis? All ambiguities are equally common, in terms of the set of forms that can be generated.

Comment: All written English sentences are multiply ambiguous, though when pronounced they are usually not. If you want to see how ambiguous a sentence can be, take a look at [Stephen Abney's famous paper on the subject](http://www.vinartus.net/spa/95c.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for:

https://cs.nyu.edu/faculty/davise/ai/ambiguity.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_gap

Answer (score 2):

[partial answer]

Your example has elision (ellipsis) ambiguity.  The best paraphrases simply add the missing words that the listener is expected to assume: (rather than change the existing syntax as you did in your interpretations)

John likes Adam more than [John likes] Eve.

John likes Adam more than Eve [likes Adam].

Elision can also cause (polysemous) transitivity errors: "He is running [for office]."

Other ambiguities arise from polysemous words, which can cause parsing of the wrong Part-Of-Speech or choosing the wrong idiom: "They can fish."  "The cat is on the TV again."

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no such list can exist. According to standard models, language is infinite and recursive, and there are infinitely many different ways a sentence can be made ambiguous.

For example, imagine the structural rules `NP → NP and NP` and `NP → NP 's NP`. (Or `DP` instead depending on your theory, but calling it an `NP` here is simpler.) With only these two, you can already create an infinite number of ambiguous sentences: "my brother's dog and cat", "my brother's dog and cat's name", etc etc.

Comment: I've edited this to note that I'm just looking for a list of **common** syntax ambiguities. I'm not expecting a complete list, for I know that there's not a finite quantity of syntax ambiguities.